# Refactoring JTextFields

Tags: java

I've refactored numerous fields on a JTabbedPane to reduce redundancy. However, I'm getting a null pointer exception when I've set a constant size for the number of fields. I'm not exactly sure as to why this is occurring. What did I do wrong, and more importantly could someone explain what's going on?

```
public class JDBC_GUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    private static final int WINNER_SIZE = 4;
    private JTextField[] winner_fields = new JTextField[WINNER_SIZE];


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel winners_tab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Winners", null, winners_tab, null);
        winners_tab.setLayout(null);

        for(int i = 0; i < WINNER_SIZE; i++) {
            winner_fields[i].setBounds(212, 30 + (i * 40), 134, 28);
            winners_tab.add(winner_fields[i]);
            winner_fields[i].setColumns(10);
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception Message:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at JDBC_GUI.initialize(JDBC_GUI.java:60)
at JDBC_GUI.<init>(JDBC_GUI.java:41)
at JDBC_GUI$1.run(JDBC_GUI.java:28)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: do you ever add anything to the winner_fields array?

Comment: please show the exception trace

Comment: Looks like you didn't put anything in the `winner_fields` array.

Comment: You're right @JohnKane I can't believe I didn't see that. That hint really reminded me of that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't put anything in the `winner_fields` array, so referencing it here will throw a null pointer:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < WINNER_SIZE; i++) {
        winner_fields[i].setBounds(212, 30 + (i * 40), 134, 28);
        winners_tab.add(winner_fields[i]);
        winner_fields[i].setColumns(10);
    }
```

Possible fix might be:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < WINNER_SIZE; i++) {
        winner_fields[i] = new JTextField();
        winner_fields[i].setBounds(212, 30 + (i * 40), 134, 28);
        winners_tab.add(winner_fields[i]);
        winner_fields[i].setColumns(10);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for pointing out that critical point. I should've known better!

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding! :D

Answer (score 1):

At the point that this line executes:

```
 winner_fields[i].setBounds(212, 30 + (i * 40), 134, 28);
```

You haven't put anything in the `winner_fields` array. All the elements are initialized to the default value for their type, in this case `null`. So `winner_fields[i]` will return `null`, resulting in an NPE when you try to call `setBounds()` on it.

The solution is to initialize the field before you use it:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < WINNER_SIZE; i++) {
        winner_fields[i] = new JTextField();
        winner_fields[i].setBounds(212, 30 + (i * 40), 134, 28);
        winners_tab.add(winner_fields[i]);
        winner_fields[i].setColumns(10);
    }
```

Comment: I Just figured this out, I'm such a goof! I forgot to initialize a JTextField. Another silly mistake :-) (This is what happens when you try to refactor 500 lines later...)